# Adjust alignment of pop-up menus in gnome shell

Tags: gnome, gui, gnome-shell, menu

I use arc-dark theme in combo with dash-to-panel extension, and I don't like how the pop-up menus align with the buttons. They are way off on the right, as you can see in this example:

[image: menu misaligned 1]

Is it there any way to tweak this alignment?

Comment: See this issue: https://github.com/NicoHood/arc-theme/issues/108